# Preferring composition over inheritance in the diamond problem

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, diamond-problem

Suppose we have 3 classes `Button`, `Clickable` and `Rectangle`.
Neither of them are abstract and can exist on their own. All of them have a `position` member variable. When the `Button` class inherits from `Clickable` and `Rectangle` they should share a common `position` variable.
My implementation:

```
struct Positionable {
    struct Position {
        int x, y;
    } position;
};
struct Rectangle: virtual public Positionable {
    // ...
};
struct Clickable : virtual public Positionable {
    // ...
};
struct Button : virtual public Positionable, public Rectangle, public Clickable {
    Button() {
        this->position.x = 1;
        assert(Rectangle::position.x == 1);
        assert(Clickable::position.x == 1);
        assert(Positionable::position.x == 1);
    }
} test;
```

The problem with this (besides the 3 forms of the word *position*) is that I feel, that I'm breaking the composition over inheritance principle, because I inherit only to include a variable.
Is there a design pattern with the same behavior? How can I use composition in this situation?

##### EDIT:

I'm looking for a solution where the `Button` inherits from `Clickable` and from `Rectangle`, because it's an is-a relationship. (It might not be the best example, but assume that it's true)
I also don't want to inherit from `Positionable`, because it's a has-a relationship.
And I want the same behavior like my implementation, so:

- All of them have a `Position position`
- When they inherit from each other, they share this variable
- I don't use setters/getters

Basically I want something like virtual variables, but c++ doesn't have that feature yet, so I'm looking for a sensible replacement.

Comment: Would you be better off with [policy based design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872675/policy-based-design-and-best-practices-c)?

Comment: It's an interesting design, but I'm not sure how could I apply here.

Comment: Button is the user of the policies "Shape" and "Action" which can be filled with "Rectangle" and "Clickable".

Comment: Not sure `Clickable` should have `Position`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see your problem exactly, however you can use references to achieve this. You can do something like:

```cpp
struct Position{
    int x,y;
};

class Rectangle {
    public:
        Rectangle(Position& p) : pos(p) {}
        ~Rectangle() {}
        Position getPos(){ return pos; }
    protected:
        Position& pos;
};

class Clickable {
    public:
        Clickable(Position& p) : pos(p) {}
        ~Clickable() {}
        Position getPos(){ return pos; }
    protected:
        Position& pos;
};

class Button {
    public:
        Button(int x, int y) : pos({x,y}), a(this->pos), b(this->pos) {}
        ~Button() {}
        Position getPos(){ return pos; }
    protected:
        Position pos;
        Clickable a;
        Rectangle b;
};
```

This is very messy though. Also it makes it a pain to use the raw `Rectangle`, and `Clickable` classes if you ask me. Pointers can achieve this as well, if that is what you prefer.

Comment: If opinion based questions would be allowed on stackoverflow my main question would have been that is it an anti-pattern or not. The problem is that if I want to include more variables I need to make a bunch of useless structs and have to inherit from them, which can be hard to understand for the programmer who would see my code, because every inheritance can hide any number of variables and functions. Probably I want something like virtual variables, but I hoped that there is a nice workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Inheritance models an is-a relationship. If `Horse` inherits from `Animal`, then a `Horse` *is an* `Animal`, because all properties an animal has are also properties of a horse.

Now, in your example, does it make sense to say that a `Button` is `Clickable`? Yes, so inheritance is an applicable tool for the job. Does it make sense to say that a `Button` is a `Rectangle`? Well, now we get into muddy waters.

If we intend to use a `Button` through its `Rectangle` sub-interface (perhaps a simple renderer could take in rectangle-deriving objects and render them), then inheritance is also appropriate here. But if inheritance is used *because it's proper OOP and it's what needs to be done*, then no.

Weigh what you need, see if it makes logical sense. Think if you should, before you think if you could.

PS: I don't understand why `Clickable` isn't abstract. It sounds like an interface. If it isn't an interface, perhaps there's a better name for the concept you are trying to model.

**EDIT**

It occurred to me that, if you are using C++, you might want to look into `private` inheritance. This is the kind of *implementation-inheritance* you are talking about. C++ FAQ about it: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/private-inheritance

Comment: My problem isn't about the relationship between `Button` , `Rectangle` and `Clickable`, I want these to be given. I wasn't really clear about this, so I updated my question.
The problem that I don't want to inherit from `Positionable `, because it's not an is-a relationship and it doesn't have any functionality, but I still want the shared `position` variable.

Comment: Thank you for updating the question, I'm sorry I misunderstood. Privately and virtually inheriting from `Positionable` seems to me like an alright approach. It has the semantics you want, without exposing this inheritance to the outside. If you want to *completely* avoid inheritance, then you might try keeping a `std::shared_ptr<Position>` as a member that's distinct for every class and setting that to point to the same position instance, so it's effectively shared. I think this solution is worse though, because of the dynamic allocation.